# How can i apply a filter to a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

I am trying to create a multiple filter on multiple arrays, but i can't figure out how to filter the nested array without duplicating it. I am using vuejs with a few plugins that are using the array so i can't actually change it, just filter.

I am using draggablevue to display a list of arrays that can be sorted around.
 I want the main array to stay untouched and just filter "inv" array by name or code.
I've played around with forEach, map, filter but i can't find anything online to help me with this issue.

```
let invNameFilter = " cadeira";
let invCodeNameFilter = "1234";
let salas = [
        {
          name: "Sala 1.14",
          inv: [
            {
              name: "cadeira",
              inventoryCode: "1234"
            },
            {
              name: "quadro",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            },
            {
              name: "mesa",
              inventoryCode: "1234"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Sala 1.12",
          inv: [
            {
              name: "mesa",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            },
            {
              name: "cadeira",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

```
let invNameFilter = " cadeira";
let invCodeNameFilter = "1234";
let salas = [
        {
          name: "Sala 1.14",
          inv: [
            {
              name: "cadeira",
              inventoryCode: "1234"
            },
            {
              name: "mesa",
              inventoryCode: "1234"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Sala 1.12",
          inv: [
            {
              name: "cadeira",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

Comment: Can't have it both ways...either have to duplicate into filtered copy or mutate original. So which should it be?

Comment: You could potentially normalize your data, and keep `inv` in separate object of arrays (with name as key). Then it’d be more workable.

Comment: Maybe you should create `computed` property for it. For example `filteredSalas`. I can write code for it.

Comment: @EvilArthas That is the aprouch i need, because i can't change the original array. My only issue is that i can't figure out how to filter the "inv" array to show only matching objects.

Comment: @TheWitness That is probably the best aprouch, i already have a "normalized" database. This is for a school project and that is one of the requirements. I can build the page with the normalized data and i don't need any complicated filters.

Comment: I am going to chagne my answer, using **Vue.js** `computed` property.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object structure remains the same, you can use a mix of `map`, `filter` and `Object spread` operations to accomplish.

- Map (since you need all the outer objects)
- Spread operation (To override `inv` since that is to be filtered)
- Filter on `inv` (Apply your filter function to return the desired result)

```js
const salas = [
  {
    name: "Sala 1.14",
    inv: [
      {
        name: "cadeira",
        inventoryCode: "1234"
      },
      {
        name: "quadro",
        inventoryCode: "4321"
      },
      {
        name: "mesa",
        inventoryCode: "1234"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sala 1.12",
    inv: [
      {
        name: "mesa",
        inventoryCode: "4321"
      },
      {
        name: "cadeira",
        inventoryCode: "4321"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const filteredSalas = salas.map(x => ({
                        ...x, 
                        inv: x.inv.filter(k => k.name === "cadeira" || k.inventoryCode === "1234") 
                      }))

console.log(filteredSalas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this code does not mtate initial `salas` array.

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      name: "cadeira",
      code: "1234",
      salas: [{
          name: "Sala 1.14",
          inv: [{
              name: "cadeira",
              inventoryCode: "1234"
            },
            {
              name: "quadro",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            },
            {
              name: "mesa",
              inventoryCode: "1234"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Sala 1.12",
          inv: [{
              name: "mesa",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            },
            {
              name: "cadeira",
              inventoryCode: "4321"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredSalas() {
      // as alternative use _.deepClone (lodash function)
      const arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.salas));

      arr.forEach(obj => {
        obj.inv = obj.inv.filter(item => item.name === this.name && item.inventoryCode === this.code);
      });

      return arr;
    }
  },
  template: "<div>{{ filteredSalas }}</div>"
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```